# Mat_<unsigned char> in opencv - Mat datatypes

Tags: c++, c, opencv, mat

In the below code if I read image using `imread` the image is displaying differently and if the source is camera it is showing normal colored image. And below is the code.

Can some one explain bit in detail with some good link if possible?

```
int main () {

    cv :: Mat_<unsigned char> src;
    cv :: VideoCapture cap(0);

    while ( 1 ) {
        cap >> src;
//      src = cv :: imread ( "C:\\Users\\hubuser10\\Desktop\\1.jpg" );

        imshow ( "test image", src );
        cv :: waitKey(1);
    }

}
```

**Result from imread:**[image]

**Camera image:**

[image]

Comment: Downvoter kindly add the reason. So that I can improve my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `VideoCapture` and `imread` without additional parameter returns 3-channels BGR frames. Use `cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b>` type.